# Clean up on aisles [outsourcing], [technology-stack], [market-share] and [conferences]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

While the [outsourcing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outsourcing), [technology-stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/technology-stack), [market-share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/market-share) and [conferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conferences) tags don't have many questions individually, there's about 100 questions all-told that need to be cleaned up, and in all likelihood, deleted.

I've cast close votes on a large number of these, but they've all aged off, so instead of pestering mods to clean it up, I thought I'd bring it to the attention of this lovely Meta community.

Some goodies include:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485393/outsourcing-and-software-engineering
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510294/technologies-and-languages-to-use-for-a-personal-website
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238171/statistics-regarding-windows-xp-before-sp2-is-it-worth-still-supporting-it
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833558/anyone-been-to-the-stareast-qa-conference
- [What are the main differences between Dart and Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23459245/what-are-the-main-differences-between-dart-and-go)

Comment: You can re-cast aged votes now, right? Or am I thinking of something else?

Comment: PIty that *Anyone been to the StarEast QA conference* question is closed now. I could earn the peer preasure badge there by answering *I've never been to STAR East*.

Comment: All these tags are gone now